# How to programmatically set error on [formControl] through component ts file in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, validation, autocomplete, ngx-bootstrap

I have a for which basically uses template driven from (Using ngModel bindings). But few of the inputs(here mat-autocomplete) are using [formControl] bindings. I want to **show error on this input when user enters free text and does not select** any of the option from autocomplete dropdown(ngx-bootstrap typeahead customized). I'm able to get required field error. 
How can I achieve this?

My template:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #addAssignmentForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addAssignmentForm.form.valid && createAssignment()">
    <div class="wrapper wrapper-content myWrapper">
      <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Select Hospital"
        #hospitalInput
        aria-label="Number"
        [formControl]="searchHospital"
        matInput
        [matAutocomplete]="hospitalAutoComplete"
        required
      />
      <mat-autocomplete #hospitalAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWith" showPanel="true" (optionsScroll)="onHospitalScroll()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredHospitals$ | async" [value]="option">
          {{ option?.name }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
      <div *ngIf="(addAssignmentForm.submitted || searchHospital.dirty) && searchHospital.invalid">
        <span *ngIf="searchHospital?.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Please select a hospital</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my component, I tried:

```
formData.form.controls['email'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});
```

But this throws error `formData.form.controls['email']` is undefined

Comment: Maybe using both formControls and ngModel is a wrong way to use, but mat-autocomplete is not working on ngModel binding

Comment: Faizan, "searchHospital" is a **FormControl** (I supouse you has a `serchHospital:FormControl=new FormControl()`  in your .ts. I can't see formData nor form, BTW the way yo access is `formGroup.get('nameOfFormControl').setErrrors(...)`

Comment: @Eliseo true, I defined using FormControl(). Solved using `this.searchHospital.setErrors({ invalid: true });` based on condition

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger the error state by set validators on the reactive form controls like so:

TS

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  textLimit: [countingValue, {
    validators: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]*'), Validators.min(1), Validators.maxLength(20)],
    updateOn: 'change'
  }]
});
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput
             [placeholder]="Add some numbers"
             formControlName="textLimit">
      <mat-error>Please use only numbers</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

The validators like `Validators.required` or `Validators.pattern('[0-9]*')` ensures that the form changes its state to `form.valid = false;` when the validators are not fulfilled. Then the error component `<mat-error>` will be triggered inside the `<mat-form-field>`

### In your example

In your example you would have something like:

TS:

```
this.searchHospital = new FormControl('',[/* Validators */]);
```

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" [formControl]="searchHospital" />
    <mat-error>Something is wrong</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

For more information about error-handling in reactive forms please read

- https://angular.io/guide/form-validation
- https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms